# hashmap initialization with preexisting values?

Tags: java

If i have an `int[] array = {1, 2, 3}` and I want to initialise the hashmap with values below, is there a better way to do it ?

```
Map<Integer,Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer,Boolean>();
            map.put(1,false);
            map.put(2,false);
            map.put(3,false);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
for (int i: array) {
    map.put(i, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/),

```
ImmutableMap.of(1, false, 2, false, 3, false);
```

or,

```
ImmutableMap.builder().put(1, false).put(2, false).put(3, false).build()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to initialize is:

```
Map<Integer,Boolean> map =  new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>() {
                            {
                                put(1,false);
                                put(2,false);
                                put(3,false);
                            }
```

Comment: This creates an anonymous subclass of HashMap, which may or may not be OK depending on your circumstances.  I wouldn't recommend it without at least understanding the cost / downsides.